# Add views programmatically to Fragment onCreateView method

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using fragments to build an android app for API15.

Layouts are:

1. activity_page_detail.xml
2. activity_page_list.xml
3. activity_page_twopane.xml
4. fragment_page_detail.xml

Java Files are:

1. pageDetailActivity.java
2. pageDetailFragment.java
3. pageListActivity.java
4. pageListFragment.java
5. DummyContent.java

In activity_page_detail.xml :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/page_detail_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".pageDetailActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"/>
```

And in activity_page_list.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="contentDescription"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" 
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/page_list"
    android:name="com.application.trigger.pageListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    tools:context=".pageListActivity"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And in activity_page_twopane.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:showDividers="middle"
tools:context=".pageListActivity" >

<!--
This layout is a two-pane layout for the pages
master/detail flow. See res/values-large/refs.xml and
res/values-sw600dp/refs.xml for an example of layout aliases
that replace the single-pane version of the layout with
this two-pane version.

For more on layout aliases, see:
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters
-->



<fragment
    android:id="@+id/page_list"
    android:name="com.application.trigger.pageListFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/page_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And in fragment_page_detail.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".pageDetailFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
tools:ignore="contentDescription"
android:background="#000">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/page_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textColor="#fafafa"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textAppearance="@android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    />

<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/linear_vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="#7f7f7f"
   />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java Source Codes are :

```
package com.application.trigger;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


/**
 * An activity representing a list of pages. This activity
 * has different presentations for handset and tablet-size devices. On
 * handsets, the activity presents a list of items, which when touched,
 * lead to a {@link pageDetailActivity} representing
 * item details. On tablets, the activity presents the list of items and
 * item details side-by-side using two vertical panes.
 * <p>
 * The activity makes heavy use of fragments. The list of items is a
 * {@link pageListFragment} and the item details
 * (if present) is a {@link pageDetailFragment}.
 * <p>
 * This activity also implements the required
 * {@link pageListFragment.Callbacks} interface
 * to listen for item selections.
 */
public class pageListActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements pageListFragment.Callbacks {

/**
 * Whether or not the activity is in two-pane mode, i.e. running on a tablet
 * device.
 */
private boolean mTwoPane;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_list);

    if (findViewById(R.id.page_detail_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the
        // large-screen layouts (res/values-large and
        // res/values-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the
        // activity should be in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;

        // In two-pane mode, list items should be given the
        // 'activated' state when touched.
        ((pageListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.page_list))
                .setActivateOnItemClick(true);
    }

    // TODO: If exposing deep links into your app, handle intents here.
}

/**
 * Callback method from {@link pageListFragment.Callbacks}
 * indicating that the item with the given ID was selected.
 */
@Override
public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    if (mTwoPane) {
        // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
        // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
        // fragment transaction.
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(pageDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        pageDetailFragment fragment = new pageDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.page_detail_container, fragment)
                .commit();

    } else {
        // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
        // for the selected item ID.
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, pageDetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(pageDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
}
}
```

And

```
package com.application.trigger;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.application.trigger.dummy.DummyContent;

/**
 * A list fragment representing a list of pages. This fragment
 * also supports tablet devices by allowing list items to be given an
 * 'activated' state upon selection. This helps indicate which item is
 * currently being viewed in a {@link pageDetailFragment}.
 * <p>
 * Activities containing this fragment MUST implement the {@link Callbacks}
 * interface.
 */
public class pageListFragment extends ListFragment {
/**
 * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
 * activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";

/**
 * The fragment's current callback object, which is notified of list item
 * clicks.
 */
private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

/**
 * The current activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

/**
 * A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must
 * implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item
 * selections.
 */
public interface Callbacks {
    /**
     * Callback for when an item has been selected.
     */
    public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

/**
 * A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does
 * nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity.
 */
private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    }
};

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public pageListFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // TODO: replace with a real list adapter.
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            DummyContent.ITEMS));
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
    if (savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
        setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
    if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
    }

    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
    mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
    }
}

/**
 * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
 * given the 'activated' state when touched.
 */
public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
    // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
    // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
    getListView().setChoiceMode(activateOnItemClick
            ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
            : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
}

private void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
    if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
    } else {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    mActivatedPosition = position;
}
}
```

And :

```
    package com.application.trigger;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    /**
     * An activity representing a single page detail screen. This
     * activity is only used on handset devices. On tablet-size devices,
     * item details are presented side-by-side with a list of items
     * in a {@link pageListActivity}.
     * <p>
     * This activity is mostly just a 'shell' activity containing nothing
     * more than a {@link pageDetailFragment}.
     */

    public class pageDetailActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_detail);

        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // savedInstanceState is non-null when there is fragment state
        // saved from previous configurations of this activity
        // (e.g. when rotating the screen from portrait to landscape).
        // In this case, the fragment will automatically be re-added
        // to its container so we don't need to manually add it.
        // For more information, see the Fragments API guide at:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
        //
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Create the detail fragment and add it to the activity
            // using a fragment transaction.
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putString(pageDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID,
                    getIntent().getStringExtra(pageDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID));
            pageDetailFragment fragment = new pageDetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.page_detail_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
                // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
                // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
                // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
                //
                // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
                //
                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, pageListActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

And :

```
package com.application.trigger.dummy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Helper class for providing sample content for user interfaces created by
 * Android template wizards.
 * <p>
 * TODO: Replace all uses of this class before publishing your app.
 */
public class DummyContent {
/**
 * An array of sample (dummy) items.
 */
public static List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<DummyItem>();

/**
 * A map of sample (dummy) items, by ID.
 */
public static Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, DummyItem>();

static {
    // Add 3 sample items.
    addItem(new DummyItem("1", "ListItem-1"));
    addItem(new DummyItem("2", "ListItem-2"));
    addItem(new DummyItem("3", "ListItem-3"));
    addItem(new DummyItem("4", "ListItem-4"));
    addItem(new DummyItem("5", "ListItem-5"));
}

private static void addItem(DummyItem item) {
    ITEMS.add(item);
    ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
}

/**
 * A dummy item representing a piece of content.
 */
public static class DummyItem {
    public String id;
    public String content;

    public DummyItem(String id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return content;
    }
}
}
```

And finally the code file related to my question is:

```
        package com.application.trigger;

        import java.util.ArrayList;

        import android.content.ContentValues;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.provider.ContactsContract;
        import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;
        import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization;
        import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
        import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website;
        import android.provider.ContactsContract.Data;
        import android.provider.ContactsContract.Intents.Insert;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.LinearLayout;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import com.application.trigger.dummy.DummyContent;

        /**
         * A fragment representing a single page detail screen.
         * This fragment is either contained in a {@link pageListActivity}
         * in two-pane mode (on tablets) or a {@link pageDetailActivity}
         * on handsets.
         */
        public class pageDetailFragment extends Fragment {
            /**
             * The fragment argument representing the item ID that this fragment
             * represents.
             */
            public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

            /**
             * The dummy content this fragment is presenting.
             */
            private DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;

            /**
             * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
             * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
             */
            public pageDetailFragment() {
            }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
                // Load the dummy content specified by the fragment
                // arguments. In a real-world scenario, use a Loader
                // to load content from a content provider.
                mItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
                getActivity().setTitle(mItem.content);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page_detail, container, false);

            // show each product specification
            //passing data to each page

            if (mItem != null) {
                switch (Integer.parseInt(mItem.id)) {
                case 1:
                    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.page_detail))
                    .setText("show text1");

                    final LinearLayout row1 = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                    row1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    row1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    row1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    final TextView text1 = new TextView(getActivity());
                    text1.setText("some sample text");
                    text1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    final ImageView image1 = new ImageView(getActivity());
                    image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);

                    row1.addView(text1);
                    row1.addView(image1);

                    //LinearLayout vertical = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_vertical);
                    //vertical.addView(row1);
                    ((ViewGroup)rootView).addView(row1);

                    break;
                case 2:
                    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.page_detail))
                    .setText("show text2");

                    break;
                case 3:
                    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.page_detail))
                    .setText("show text3");

                    break;
                case 4:
                    Intent contact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
                    contact.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);

                    ArrayList<ContentValues> data = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();

                    ContentValues company = new ContentValues();
                    company.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                    company.put(Organization.COMPANY, "company name");
                    data.add(company);

                    ContentValues mobile = new ContentValues();
                    mobile.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                    mobile.put(Phone.NUMBER, "9898989898");
                    data.add(mobile);

                    ContentValues phone = new ContentValues();
                    phone.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                    phone.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_WORK);
                    phone.put(Phone.NUMBER, "9898989898");
                    data.add(phone);

                    ContentValues email = new ContentValues();
                    email.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                    email.put(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_WORK);
                    email.put(Email.ADDRESS, "info@company.com");
                    data.add(email);

                    ContentValues website = new ContentValues();
                    website.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Website.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                    website.put(Website.URL, "http://company.com");     
                    data.add(website);

                    contact.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Insert.DATA, data);

                    int request_Code = 100;
                    startActivityForResult(contact, request_Code);

                    break;

                case 5:
                    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.page_detail))
                    .setText("show text5");

                    break;
                }
            }

            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

**The Question is that** How to add view programmatically for each fragment detail at the last java code perhaps in onCreateView method? My Code at the mentioned function at case 1 exits the program and not works.

Here is the related Stack Trace:

```
08-04 06:19:35.623: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1153): GC_CONCURRENT freed 84K, 3% free 9379K/9607K, paused 4ms+4ms
08-04 06:19:39.283: WARN/WindowManager(89): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21015
08-04 06:19:43.063: INFO/ActivityManager(89): START {cmp=com.application.trigger/.pageDetailActivity (has extras)} from pid 1153
08-04 06:19:43.074: WARN/WindowManager(89): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21010
08-04 06:19:43.233: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1153): Shutting down VM
08-04 06:19:43.233: WARN/dalvikvm(1153): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2ba041f8)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.application.trigger/com.application.trigger.pageDetailActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3337)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3208)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3165)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3145)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at com.application.trigger.pageDetailFragment.onCreateView(pageDetailFragment.java:98)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:556)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1133)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4475)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1929)
08-04 06:19:43.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1153):     ... 11 more
08-04 06:19:43.293: WARN/ActivityManager(89):   Force finishing activity com.application.trigger/.pageDetailActivity
08-04 06:19:43.323: WARN/ActivityManager(89):   Force finishing activity com.application.trigger/.pageListActivity
08-04 06:19:43.633: INFO/Process(89): Sending signal. PID: 1153 SIG: 3
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that by "case 1 exits the program and not works" you mean the application crashed, in which case there is a stack trace printed out logcat.  Looking at that trace (and posting it here) will be infinitely helpful in debugging your problem.

Comment: I placed that stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack trace clearly says that the problem is that you are trying to add a View that is already attached to a ViewGroup (its parent) to another VIewGroup.

A view cannot have two different parents, hence the error.

You could remove the view from its parent before adding it to the new parent, or simply inflate the same XML several times. If you inflate one XML more that one you will be creating new View objects,and you could attach them to different parents.